# Ionic 4 and Firebase: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I've some apps working with Firebase using Firestore ddbb but this is the only one using Ionic 4.

This is my code:

```
...
private db: AngularFireDatabase
...
    const newspaperListRef = this.db.list<Newspaper>('newspapers', ref => ref.orderByKey());
    newspapersList$: Observable<Newspaper[]> = this.firebaseService.newspaperListRef.valueChanges();
```

Rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /newspapers/{newspaperId} {
      allow read; // from public
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // Allow requests from authenticated users
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data